# eliminating parameter in 3d curved line where functions contain a fractional exponent

Tags: exponential-function, parametric

I have the following equations which I use to describe a color in three dimensions (x and y are chromaticity coordinates and z is lightness):

$x = \frac{t^{2.4}}{t^{2.4} + (0.4t + 0.6)^{2.4} + 1}$

$y = \frac{1}{t^{2.4} + (0.4t + 0.6)^{2.4} + 1}$

$z = 0.0722 + (0.2126(t^{2.4})) + (0.7152((0.4t + 0.6)^{2.4}))$

where $0 \le t \le 1$

How would I go about eliminating the parameter $t$?  The fractional exponent (which represents gamma transformation) seems to make this feat impossible.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:  divide the first two equations:

$$
t^{2.4} = \frac{x}{y} \tag{1}
$$

Invert the second equation, and use $(1)\,$:

$$
(0.4t+0.6)^{2.4} = \frac{1}{y} - t^{2.4}-1 = \frac{1-x}{y} - 1 \tag{2}
$$

Substitute $(1)$ and $(2)$ in the third equation to eliminate $t$ and get a relation between $x,y,z\,$.

Comment: Thank you. thank you, thank you dxiv... you are wonderful!

Comment: One more thing, @dxiv.  What if I was only concerned with the x and y functions?  I attempted to set t = (x/y)^2.4 but things quickly got complicated.

Comment: @gmculp Indeed, substituting $t=(x/y)^{1/2.4}$ back into the equation for $y$ will give you a relation between $x$ and $y\,$. It may not be a pretty one, but that's the relation you have:$$x + y + (0.4 x^{1/2.4} + 0.6 y^{1/2.4})^{2.4} = 1$$

Comment: Excellent... thank you so very much!